# How to extract specific key values from JSON data?

Tags: json, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I am working with the JSON data which is as follows:

```
[{'_index': 'abc', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '1', '_score': None, '_source': {'ColA': 'AZ', 'ColB': 'BY', 'ColC': 'CX', 'ColD': 'DW', 'ColE': 'EV'}},{'_index': 'abc', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '2', '_score': None, '_source': {'ColA': 'GT', 'ColB': 'HS', 'ColC': 'IR', 'ColD': 'JQ', 'ColE': 'KP'}},........]
```

From here, I need to extract ColA, ColB and ColD values. I tried json_normalize method which was working fine in Jupyter Notebook but giving me error in AWS Lambda. Could anyone suggest some other method to do this?

Comment: Can you please improve your question! Include a code snippet, error message or explain what exactly is not working? Getting fields out of an event passed to lambda goes just straight forward: event[‘_index’]

Comment: Can you specified in which type of variable do you have the json? (already a list, string, oject, etc) and give us more details to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement the json that you post as an Array of Dicts( as you dont specified how do you receive it) so take this into consideration.

First of all, the JSON seems to have format errors, the json has not enclosing Brace for every element of the array, as shown bellow:

```
{'_index': 'abc', 
  '_type': '_doc', 
  '_id': '1', 
  '_score': None, 
  '_source': {'ColA': 'AZ', 
              'ColB': 'BY', 
              'ColC': 'CX', 
              'ColD': 'DW', 
              'ColE': 'EV'}, # In this place there is a } missing
```

Please validate your input json, maybe that can be the root of the problem.

So I corrected the JSON and access the elements needed:

```
l = [{'_index': 'abc', 
  '_type': '_doc', 
  '_id': '1', 
  '_score': None, 
  '_source': {'ColA': 'AZ', 
              'ColB': 'BY', 
              'ColC': 'CX', 
              'ColD': 'DW', 
              'ColE': 'EV'}},
  {'_index': 'abc', 
   '_type': '_doc', 
   '_id': '2', 
   '_score': None,
   '_source': {'ColA': 'GT', 
               'ColB': 'HS', 
               'ColC': 'IR', 
               'ColD': 'JQ', 
               'ColE': 'KP'}}]

# loop the array and extract the keys needed and apply your logic after that
for element in l:
    print(element['_source']['ColA'])
    print(element['_source']['ColB'])
    print(element['_source']['ColD'])
```